# Flask form submit can't stop when code in js has return

Tags: javascript

I want to stop form submit when the field `careerHistory` is null.

I have this judgment in my js code.

But when the field `careerHistory` is null,the html form still submitted,in fact,when this field `careerHistory` is null, I don't want to submit the form.

How to fix my code?

HTML & Javascript:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>cal</title>
        <link href="static/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <link href="static/css/FlaskModelCalculation.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <script src="static/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="static/js/toastr.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
              $('#calculate').click(function(){
              var careerHistory = $("#careerHistory").val();
              alert(careerHistory);
              if(careerHistory=="" || careerHistory==="undefined"){
                    alert("careerHistory cann't null");
                    return;//Here I don't want to to submit the form,because the careerHistory is null.But the request was sent.
                 }
              });
        });
    </script>


    </head>
    <body>
        <div align="center" style="margin-top:60px">
            <form name="form1" method='POST'>
                    <span>careerHistory</span><input type="text" placeholder="careerHistory" name="careerHistory" id="careerHistory" class="form-control" value="{{careerHistory}}"><br/>
                    <span>wholeBookNumber</span><input type="text" placeholder="wholeBookNumber" name="wholeBookNumber"  class="form-control" value="{{wholeBookNumber}}"><br/>
                    <span>reflectionBookNumber</span><input type="text" placeholder="reflectionBookNumber" name="reflectionBookNumber"  class="form-control" value="{{reflectionBookNumber}}"><br/>
                    <span>schoolClassificationCD</span><input type="text" placeholder="schoolClassificationCD" name="schoolClassificationCD" class="form-control" value="{{schoolClassificationCD}}"><br/>
                    <span>jobsNumber</span><input type="text" placeholder="jobsNumber" name="jobsNumber"  class="form-control" value="{{jobsNumber}}"><br/>
                    <span>constructionSpecificity</span><input type="text" placeholder="constructionSpecificity" name="constructionSpecificity"  class="form-control" value="{{constructionSpecificity}}"><br/>
                    <span>playingStyle</span><input type="text" placeholder="playingStyle" name="playingStyle"  class="form-control" value="{{playingStyle}}"><br/>
                    <span>workingMethod</span><input type="text" placeholder="workingMethod" name="workingMethod"  class="form-control" value="{{workingMethod}}"><br/>
                    <span>workOvertimeAverage</span><input type="text" placeholder="workOvertimeAverage" name="workOvertimeAverage"  class="form-control" value="{{workOvertimeAverage}}"><br/>
                    <input type="submit" id="calculate" class="btn btnNormal btn-primary" value="cal">
                    <input type="text"  name="calculationResult" readonly="readonly" class="form-control" value="{{calculationResult}}">
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
    <footer>
    </footer>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more of a javascript question, not a Python question actually.

You can prevent form submission using `preventDefault`

```
$(function () {
  // pass the event object as 'evt' to the callback
  $('#calculate').click(function(evt){
    var careerHistory = $("#careerHistory").val();
    if(!careerHistory) {
      // prevent form submission
      evt.preventDefault();
    }
  });
});
```

**Things you must fix first**

1) The careerHistory `input` element needs an id or class name to select the element with jQuery like you did when you set the click handler.
`<input id="careerHistory" ...>`
`$("#careerHistory")`

2) You are doing `careerHistory === "undefined"` in your if statement.
`undefined` is a keyword in javascript, not a string, so no quotes around it.

3) Empty string `""` and `undefined` are both *falsy* values.

`if (!careerHistory)`
is the same as
`if (careerHistory===false || careerHistory===null || careerHistory==="" || careerHistory===undefined || careerHistory===0)`

Comment: This is helpful!